# Maven build jar for parent module

Tags: maven, jar, module, parent

I have the following structure in the project:

```
Project -
        |- Parent // bunch of abstract classes which are used by children
                |- child_A // depend on abstract classes from Parent
                |- child_B // depend on abstract classes from Parent
                |- child_C // depend on abstract classes from Parent
```

I would like to build jars both for the parent and children as well. So I would end up with parent.jar, child_*.jar. How can I do this in maven?

Comment: Parent is tree node, so need to be `pom` module. Pom module cant produce any JAR be default - this is tree definition .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Maven tree **node** is always a project with type `pom` (*project tree definition*). Module with type `jar` is always a tree **leaf** (*generated product*). Tree **node** are named *aggregator projects* and requires 'pom' as packaging.

Your project should look like this (3-level as you ask)

```
+ Project parent (POM)
  + Abstract module (JAR) // bunch of abstract classes which are used by children
  + Implementation Modules (POM)
    + Module A (JAR) // depend on abstract classes from Abstract
    + Module B (JAR) // depend on abstract classes from Abstract
    + Module C (JAR) // depend on abstract classes from Abstract
```

Abstract Module is configured as dependency in Module A, B and C.

Comment: Stupid question why can't I have tree "dependency" structure?

Comment: This is tree :) Leaf is `jar`, project (tree) parent is `pom`. Module with type `jar` cant have submodules.

Comment: Yeah ok it's a tree. But it's just 2 level tree I would like to have 3 level tree. Root -> abstract -> concreteImpl.

Comment: This is no possible in maven. The `Node` in is always a project with type `pom`. Answer updated with 3 level tree :)

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. However if you do not mind I would like to add additional question. I don't really understand why can't I have node jar? Conceptually it should be something like "exclude child.dir" and treat current directory as leaf/module and build jar.

Comment: Try adding `<modules>` to `jar` project. Error is: `'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging.`. This is in Maven by design.

Comment: In maven one artifact = one directory. Artifact is `jar`/`war`/`ear`. List of artifacts are aggregated by parent directory `pom`. This is very different than `ant` way. Maven Standard Directory Layout is well defined.